# Shared Preferences item store

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am reposting this question since I am still stuck at this.

So I am creating a simple android application. I have a menu item which has 3 check boxes in it. As soon as my app starts, the user can select one or more from the given check boxes.but, I want to save the user selection for further reference. I achieved this for 1 of the check boxes using shared preferences but I am unable to achieve this if more than 1 check boxes are selected. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static Switch swch;
    public static boolean red = false;
    public static boolean blue = false;
    public static boolean green = false;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("checkbox", false);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.red);
//        MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.blue);
//        MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.green);
        item.setChecked(isChecked);
//        item1.setChecked(isChecked);
//        item2.setChecked(isChecked);
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.red:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.blue:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.green:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

How do I achieve this for all the switch case options using shared preferences?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a different key than checkbox to save it for other items. How exactly do you want your data saved and how do you want to retrieve and use it.

Comment: @Kapil G I want that whatever check boxes are selected by the user, the selection persist even if I reopen the app after it is killed. The above code I posted can just do it for the 1st check box. But I want the data to persist even if user selects more than 1 check boxes

Comment: Then save value for each checkbox in a different key, then get all keys when you open the activity and set the checkbox based on what values are stored in each key

Comment: Can you show a demo of how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your two methods -  `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` as shown below.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        boolean red = settings.getBoolean("red", false);
        boolean blue = settings.getBoolean("blue", false);
        boolean green = settings.getBoolean("green", false);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.color1);
        MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.color2);
        MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.color3);
        item.setChecked(red);
        item1.setChecked(blue);
        item2.setChecked(green);
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.color1:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());


                editor.putBoolean("1", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.color2:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("2", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.color3:
                item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

                editor.putBoolean("3", item.isChecked());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.item_accessibility_services:
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Thomas any reason for unselecting this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, It was just by mistake I selected this as an answer.